# React native, view got cut off when rendered in flat list

Tags: react-native

So, I'm currently working on the react native project, I trying to add a tooltip component which once user tap the item in Flatlist. it will triggered this tooltip that have several options. The problem is now it got cut off even I set the 'position' to be 'absolute' with x,y position.

Is there anyway I can overcome this problem? I tried with the zIndex as well, but still not work out.

Here is the tooltip component that I implemented.

```
export function Tooltip({
    children,
    x,
    y,
    height,
    width,
    isVisible = false,
    component,
}: TooltipProps) {

const [myWidth, setW] = useState(0)
const [myHeight, setH] = useState(0)

function onLayout({
    nativeEvent: {
        layout: {width, height},
    },
    }: LayoutChangeEvent) {
    setW(width)
    setH(height)
}

return (
    <View>
    {children}
    {isVisible && (
    <View
        onLayout={onLayout}
        style={{
        elevation: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        position: 'absolute',
    top: (height - componentHeight * 2) / 2 + y,
    left: (width - componentWidth) / 2 + x,
    }}>
        {component}
    </View>
    )}
    </View>
    )
}
```

Here is the image in the app, (I need to blur out items there, sorry for inconvenience)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tty to make parent view is SafeAreaView.
`return(<SafeAreaView><YourComponent/></SafeAreaView>)`

May be that can help.